# Por que "return false;" , em um evento de clique, cancela a abertura do link?

Tags: javascript, html

Por que o `return false` prevalece sobre, por exemplo, um href?

Temos como exemplo esse código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Uma página linda</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" onclick="return false;" title="Link pra stackoverflow" target="_blank">Melhor site de todos (Stackoverflow)</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Quando clicado, nesse caso, não aconteceria nada, devido ao `return false`.

Mas por que isso?

Por que ao clicar no link o evento de direcionamento do site não "funciona"?

Comment: Artigo interessante sobre o assunto (em inglês): http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Não é uma questão de prevalecer. O que acontece quando você clica no *link* é que é disparado em evento. Este evento apenas chama uma código que deve executar o que o programador deseja. No caso o evento chama-se `onclick` e está associando ao `a href`. O código pode fazer o que quiser ali. No caso ele não faz nada.

Foi definido na especificação (acredito eu) que este código definiria se a ação normal do clique ainda seria executada ou não baseado no retorno de um booleano fornecido por este código executado pelo evento. Então se o código retornar um `true` (se não me engano não precisa retornar alguma coisa específica para que a ação normal ocorra) a ação normal ainda é executada após a ação deste código, mas retornando `false` a ação normal é suprimida. Considera-se que tudo o que deveria ser feito já está feito pelo código.

É uma convenção útil estabelecida para dar mais flexibilidade. É apenas uma decisão simples que é tomada pelo *engine* baseada nas regras pré-estabelecidas. Imagine como seria complicado realizar certas tarefas se o *link* "funcionasse" sempre depois de você fazer uma ação. Eventualmente você teria repetição da ação ou ações conflitantes.

Exemplo:

```html
<a href="http://www.pt.stackoverflow.com/" onclick="return (confirm('Pode seguir o link?'))">SOpt</a>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/InClickReturn.js).

Hoje é possível usar algo mais moderno como o [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault).

Answer (score 10):

O @Maniero já deu uma boa explicação geral, é aquilo mesmo: foi convencionado que o `return false` cancela o comportamento padrão do elemento (no caso do clique em uma âncora, seguir o link definido no `href`, mas existem outros exemplos, em outros elementos, como cancelar o envio de um formulário).

Vou complementar aqui com alguns detalhes técnicos. Para ficar menos pesado, tentei organizá-los em forma de lista.

- A [especificação](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#events) distingue entre *event handlers* e *event listeners*. Os *handlers* são adicionados diretamente no HTML, como no seu exemplo, ou via JavaScript pela sintaxe `elemento.onevento = function(){};`. Só existe um *handler* por elemento. Os *listeners* são adicionados com [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), e pode haver mais de um por elemento.
- Esse comportamento do `return false;` de fato serve para impedir a ação padrão do elemento, e só funciona em *event handlers*, nunca em *event listeners*.
- Código JS "solto" dentro de um *handler* criado via `HTML` é sempre implicitamente embrulhado em uma função, e essa função se torna o *handler*. Como `return` só faz sentido em funções, isso explica por que ele funciona em exemplos assim:

  ```
  <a href="#" onclick="return false;">teste</a>
  ```
- Isso também explica porque isto não funciona (considere `retornaFalse` como uma função que retorna `false`):

  ```
  <a href="#" onclick="retornaFalse();">teste</a>
  ```

  ... mas isto funciona:

  ```
  <a href="#" onclick="return retornaFalse();">teste</a>
  ```
- Quando estiver usando *listeners*, existem duas maneiras de cancelar o evento:

  1. Executar o método `preventDefault` do objeto evento passado ao *listener*.
  2. Definir a propriedade `returnValue` desse mesmo objeto para `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sou um campeão de javascript, mas até onde sei o comportamento padrão é: executar a função do onclick e depois seguir o link **a menos** que o onclick retorne false.

me baseei nessa pergunta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867558/html-tag-a-want-to-add-both-href-and-onclick-working