# Qual é a diferença entre chamar uma função e retornar uma função?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho, por exemplo, uma função `myFunction()` a ser chamada no elemento `<body>` quando o evento `onbeforeunload` ocorrer:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>example</title>
</head>
<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Click here to go to w3schools.com</a>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            return "Write something clever here...";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Porém para a função `myFunction` ser chamada eu preciso dar um `return` no atributo de evento, porque dessa maneira não funciona:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>example</title>
</head>
<body onbeforeunload="myFunction()">
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Click here to go to w3schools.com</a>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            return "Write something clever here...";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por que você diz que não funciona?

Comment: No primeiro exemplo o evento beforeunload é executado já no segundo não

Comment: Ele não chama a função no segundo exemplo, apenas se eu retornar a função.

Comment: Declare o evento `onbeforeunload` no objeto window `<h1 id='titulo'>Teste</h1><script>window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {document.getElementById('titulo').innerText= 'beforeunload';});</script>`

Comment: Olá Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt, o que estou imaginando é que você está querendo apresentar o dado da sua string em algum lugar, o retorno irá retornar, mas não vai mostrar nada na sua tela porque vc não deu origem para ele,  vc teria que apresentar isso de alguma forma, tipo: `<script>var dado = myFunction();  alert(dado);</script>`

Comment: ou: `<script>var retornado = myFunction(); document.body.innerText = retornado;</script>`

Comment: @IvanFerrer Esse evento beforeunload é especial, por conta da "tradição" e do contexto sensível ele exibe automaticamente um confirm com o texto retornado pelo event handler.

Comment: Sim, o beforeunload é uma função de auto-envocação que captura um retorno antes de qualquer evento do ser carregado. [+]

Comment: [+] ela captura o que vc processa dentro da função e necessita que tenha um retorno, por isso não faz sentido não retorná-la, mas a função que é chamada pode executar um script, ou uma subFuncao, não precisa necessariamente de nada além de um `return ...` externo.

Comment: Ao bater uma página o exemplo a seguir será chamado: `var change = true;  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if (change) {
           return 'Há modificações para serem salvas. Are you sure you want to leave?';
        }`
     }

Answer (score 6):

Em resumo, é por conta deste [ponto da especificação](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes):

> *Event handler content attributes, when specified, must contain valid JavaScript code which, when parsed, would match the FunctionBody production after automatic semicolon insertion.*

Ou seja:

> Atributos [HTML] correspondentes a *event handlers*, quando especificados, precisam conter código JavaScript válido que, quando analisado, corresponda a uma produção FunctionBody após a inserção automática de ponto-e-vírgula.

Em outras palavras, o código que você coloca no `onbeforeunload` é executado como se fosse o corpo de uma função, e esse `return` determina o que essa função retorna. O valor de retorno do event handler é usado em alguns eventos para cancelar o evento, caso o handler retorne `false`. Se você retornar `false` para o `unbeforeunload`, o unload da página é cancelado.

O mesmo mecanismo pode ser utilizado para cancelar a função de uma âncora (link), por exemplo:

```html
<a href="https://google.com" onclick="return false">Este link não funciona</a>
```

No caso específico do evento `beforeunload`, ele exibe algo semelhante a um `confirm`, contendo a mensagem que for retornada pelo event handler. O código que está na pergunta faz basicamente isso:

```
<body onbeforeunload="return 'Mensagem a ser exibida'">
```

E, no caso específico desse evento, quem retorna `false` para cancelar o unload é a janela modal de `confirm`, caso o usuário clique em "cancelar".

Tem mais alguns detalhes sobre esse mecanismo todo na [minha resposta à pergunta linkada no topo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51967/74).